# Get to the bottom of this Connect-Wall

Tags: connect-wall

Find the links to divide the words into four equal groups, then link the main word from all four links to get the one word answer.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bird | Blood Source | Dancer | [Estries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estries) |
| Family | Four | Magic | Mound |
| Orange | Ping | Public | Room |
| Rubber | Slim | Steel | Tulip |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The four connecting groups are:

> **Group 1: Words with synonyms that end with ARROW**
>  BIRD = (sp)arrow, BLOOD SOURCE = [(m)arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_marrow), MOUND = [(b)arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumulus), SLIM = (n)arrow
>
>  **Group 2: Can follow TAP ___**
>  (tap)DANCER, (tap)ESTRIES, (tap)PING, (tap)ROOM
>
>  **Group 3: Can precede ___ SQUARE**
>  MAGIC square, PUBLIC square, [FOUR square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_square), [STEEL square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_square)
>
>  **Group 4: Can precede ___ TREE**
>  FAMILY tree, ORANGE tree, RUBBER tree, [TULIP tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liriodendron)

The final connection between these four groups is:

> **ROOT** - a word which also means 'bottom', as in the title ('get to the root of...'):
>  [ARROWroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowroot), [TAProot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taproot), SQUARE root, TREE root.

Comment: My puzzle was solved in only 2 hours.  Nicely done!

Comment: @Tobbs You posted on my lunch break! That first category had potential to be a real stumper but fortuitously I somehow stumbled upon it before the others :)